Cohen--Macaulay rings $R$ of dimension more than $1$ such that $R/\mathfrak p$ is also Cohen--Macaulay for every minimal prime ideal $\mathfrak p$
Let $R$ be a Cohen--Macaulay local ring. If $\dim R=1$, then $R/\mathfrak p$ is also a Cohen--Macaulay ring for every minimal prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ of $R$. It is known that for $\dim R\ge 2$, this may fail ... I want to ask:

Is there a large class of Cohen--Macaulay rings $R$, of dimension at least $2$, such that $R/\mathfrak p$ is also a Cohen--Macaulay ring for every minimal prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ of $R$ ?


I will assume that "local" = "only one maximal ideal + Noetherian" since Cohen-Macaulay is much more subtle outside the Noetherian case.
Let $\mathfrak{m}$ be the maximal ideal of $R$, and consider the short exact sequence of $R$-modules below. $$0\rightarrow \mathfrak{p} \rightarrow R \rightarrow R/\mathfrak{p} \rightarrow 0$$ This induces a long exact sequence in local cohomology, which gives $H^{j-1}_\mathfrak{m}(\mathfrak{p}) \simeq H^j_\mathfrak{m}(R/\mathfrak{p})$ for $j<\dim R$ since $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay. Furthermore, $R$ is equidimensional, that is, $\dim R/\mathfrak{p} = \dim R$ for all $\mathfrak{p}$ minimal primes of $R$. From here, one can easily see that the condition that $R/\mathfrak{p}$ is Cohen-Macaulay is equivalent to $\operatorname{depth} \mathfrak{p} \ge \dim R-1$.
I am not sure how frequently this happens, but it does seem special. Certainly, $R$ being a domain will satisfy your criteria, but not in an interesting way. In general, $\operatorname{depth} I$ is not particularly easy to compute. I will try to update my answer soon with some two-dimensional examples coming from Stanley-Reisner rings.

Yes, I'm assuming Noetherian always ... but I think your depth computation was a little off ... it should come out to be depth $\mathfrak p \ge \dim R$, i.e., $\mathfrak p$ is maximal Cohen-Macaulay as an $R$-module ... thanks to your comment about Stanley-Reisner rings, I do believe the answer is yes in that case (Stanley-Reisner localized at irrelevant maximal ideal) always, because the minimal primes should be just generated by variables so the quotient should be just polynomial ring (localized at irrelevant maximal ideal)

You are right, it should be $\dim R$ not $\dim R -1$; I'll leave this comment instead of edting. I agree with the Stanley-Reisner idea you mentioned.
